# modifying a json file of world country polygons to customise colours

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a JavaScript package which displays global flows between lat/long coordinates from a CSV file.

The JS package calls a JSON file which provides country polygon shape data.  I would like some of the countries to appear in different colours. Being unfamiliar with JSON, I am struggling to modify the code to achieve this customization. I have looked through various tutorials but still getting errors or no effect at all.

Here is example JSON code for Afghanistan:

{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [61.210817, 35.650072],
                    [62.230651, 35.270664],
                    [62.984662, 35.404041],
                    [63.193538, 35.857166],
                    [63.982896, 36.007957],
                    [64.546479, 36.312073],
                    [64.746105, 37.111818],
                    [65.588948, 37.305217],
                    [65.745631, 37.661164],
                    [66.217385, 37.39379],
                    [66.518607, 37.362784],
                    [67.075782, 37.356144],
                    [67.83, 37.144994],
                    [68.135562, 37.023115],
                    [68.859446, 37.344336],
                    [69.196273, 37.151144],
                    [69.518785, 37.608997],
                    [70.116578, 37.588223],
                    [70.270574, 37.735165],
                    [70.376304, 38.138396],
                    [70.806821, 38.486282],
                    [71.348131, 38.258905],
                    [71.239404, 37.953265],
                    [71.541918, 37.905774],
                    [71.448693, 37.065645],
                    [71.844638, 36.738171],
                    [72.193041, 36.948288],
                    [72.63689, 37.047558],
                    [73.260056, 37.495257],
                    [73.948696, 37.421566],
                    [74.980002, 37.41999],
                    [75.158028, 37.133031],
                    [74.575893, 37.020841],
                    [74.067552, 36.836176],
                    [72.920025, 36.720007],
                    [71.846292, 36.509942],
                    [71.262348, 36.074388],
                    [71.498768, 35.650563],
                    [71.613076, 35.153203],
                    [71.115019, 34.733126],
                    [71.156773, 34.348911],
                    [70.881803, 33.988856],
                    [69.930543, 34.02012],
                    [70.323594, 33.358533],
                    [69.687147, 33.105499],
                    [69.262522, 32.501944],
                    [69.317764, 31.901412],
                    [68.926677, 31.620189],
                    [68.556932, 31.71331],
                    [67.792689, 31.58293],
                    [67.683394, 31.303154],
                    [66.938891, 31.304911],
                    [66.381458, 30.738899],
                    [66.346473, 29.887943],
                    [65.046862, 29.472181],
                    [64.350419, 29.560031],
                    [64.148002, 29.340819],
                    [63.550261, 29.468331],
                    [62.549857, 29.318572],
                    [60.874248, 29.829239],
                    [61.781222, 30.73585],
                    [61.699314, 31.379506],
                    [60.941945, 31.548075],
                    [60.863655, 32.18292],
                    [60.536078, 32.981269],
                    [60.9637, 33.528832],
                    [60.52843, 33.676446],
                    [60.803193, 34.404102],
                    [61.210817, 35.650072]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "id": "AFG",
        "color": "#000"
    }]
}

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, you have one more comma at bottom of file, which make the JSON not valid - maybe this was the problem, maybe not. Try to insert data to http://jsonlint.com/ next time

Comment: You forgot the most important information - the errors themselves. Also you didn't post the actual code, so it's not possible to help you to fix it.

Comment: @libik Where should be that invalid comma exactly?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - it is no more, I removed it to properly format the JSON.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the valid JSON file with the attempted but unsuccessful colour change.

Comment: Note that this code does not produce an error, but does not have any effect on the colour properties of the polygons created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are playing with D3.
Make sure you have loaded topojson then use

```
d3.json ( url , function (error, world) {  
var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
  countries.forEach ( function (country,index) { 
    if ( country.properties.name  =="Afghanistan" ) country.properties.color ='#color';
   });
});
```

if you don't use D3 - ignore my reply ;)